# Strange error with the Test_F and EXPECT_EQ functions of GTEST

Tags: c++, linux, googletest

I'm trying to implement an extremely simple GoogleTest example in VScode on Linux and I'm getting some weird errors that I cannot find online. When I'm trying to actually define the tests that will be run -
'''

```
#include <limits.h>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include </home/tester/src/Multiply.h>
    class MultiplyTest : public ::testing::Test {
     protected:
      virtual void SetUp() {
      } 
      virtual void TearDown() {
      }
    };
    TEST_F(MultiplyTest,twoValues){
        const int x = 4;
        const int y = 5;
        Multiply multiply;
        EXPECT_EQ(20,multiply.twoValues(x,y));
        EXPECT_EQ(6,multiply.twoValues(2,3));
    }
```

'''
Errors get thrown at the TEST_F and EXPECT_EQ parts, saying specifically that TEST_F is "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier" and EXPECT_EQ is "class "testing::internal::EqHelper" has no member "Compare"."
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my multiply.h header file:

```
#ifndef _MULTIPLY_HPP_
#define _MULTIPLY_HPP_
class Multiply{
public:
    static int twoValues(const int x, const int y);  
};
#endif
```

and my makefile:

```
CXX = gcc
CXXFLAGS = -g -L/opt/gtest/lib -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread
INCS = -I./ -I../../src -I/opt/gtest/include
OBJS = ../../src/Addition.o Addition_Test.o ../../src/Multiply.o Multiply_Test.o

testAll: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCS) -o testAll  Main_TestAll.cpp $(OBJS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(INCS)

clean:
    rm testAll *.o testAll.xml
```

I'm currently running gcc 7.3.1 if that helps.

Comment: can't reproduce

Comment: Did you forget to close a `namespace` in Multiply.h?

Comment: Maybe you want `CXX = g++`